# From depth 2D image to 3D point cloud with python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, 3dcamera

I use a 3D ToF camera which streams a depth 2D image where each pixel values are a distance measurement in meters.

I know the following parameter of the camera: cx, cy, fx, fy, k1, k2, k3, p1, p2.

And I want to convert the depth 2D image into a point cloud where each pixel is converted into a point with coordinate (X, Y, Z).

I don't know what is the easiest way to do this 3D projection, using OpenCV or doing it by hand?

Comment: it's ok to do it manually, to understand what's going on. See here: http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration but it might be nice to undistort before performing "Then, using the depth camera intrinsics, each pixel (x_d,y_d) of the depth camera can be projected to metric 3D space using the following formula: "

Comment: You need to use "triangulation" equation. Opencv has all the related commands.